# windows 8 installation blacked my laptop screen

Tags: windows-8, boot, installation, windows-installer

I have installed windows 8 on my Asus K43S using a USB drive. Previous OS was preinstalled win 7 by asus. The installation (customised installation) went well where i chose to format my previous partition for win 7 and chose it to hold the new windows 8. after the restart screen, my laptop couldn't show anyhting on the screen. I press f2 to go to the bios but it does not show anyhting. The screen Totally blacked and even the Asus splash screen on boot doesn't show up. now i cannot do anything. Can someone explain this?

The screen was working well and i tried to use an external output. Still does not show anything. I'd appreciate any kind of help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I managed to fix my laptop somehow and windows 8 installation was successfully installed. I asked this question at microsoft and i put an answer there. I'll share it here as well.

First i removed the hard drive. Then i turned on my laptop. The good thing is that the bios screen returned. I installed back the drive and turned my laptop on. It successfully resumed windows 8 installation. I am glad that it worked yet disappointed of how installing windows turned out to be this difficult and troublesome.